# Unable to get CSS transitions to work with drop-down menu

Tags: css, css-transitions

To understand my situation better, please head over to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/7VuGY/) and take a look. The preview pane of the fiddle shows a preview of the menu I am building.

[image: menu preview pane]

When you click on the menu 'Channels" the menu simply shows up without any transition effect. I have no idea why.

This is the relevant code:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    width: 550px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    color: #222;

    /* See? */
    -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
    transition: height 0.35s ease;
}
```

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong there?

Comment: Could you simplify your code a bit, just limiting it to the code which processes the toggling of the menu and post it as another pen/fiddle? I think I know what your problem is but I don't have enough time right now to work through all the code in the pen to verify it.

Comment: @LeviBotelho Placed the code relevant to the menu right at the top in the CSS text-box. Okay now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it isn't obvious, I am using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) for the dropdown menu. And the transition effect that I was trying to achieve comes with the [Collapse plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse), and not [Dropdowns](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns).

Answer (score 1):

That is because the javascript is NOT CHANGING THE HEIGHT of your element (the element that appears after clicking.). Your css applies transition animation ONLY TO HEIGHT CHANGES.

your javascript changes `display:none;` of your element to `display:block;` that is why you dont see any transition effect from the css.

Comment: I also tried adding height as such: `.dropdown-menu { height: 0; } .open  > .dropdown-menu { height: auto; }` -- that changes height from 0 to `auto` when the dropdown is open. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: I havent actually looked into your javascripts, but if you are using toggle() function to make your menu appear/disappear, you can change it to toggle("slow") or toggle("fast").

Comment: Aayush, I was using the wrong plugin. See my answer. Thanks for trying to help. :)

Comment: The only thing better than finding a solution at stackoverflow.. is finding a solution on your own!! :) glad you fixed yoour problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/rakesh_vadnal/7VuGY/1/

OLD CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: absolute;
top: 36px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
width: 550px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
color: #222;
-webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease;
-moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
-o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
transition: height 0.35s ease;
height: 0;
}
.open  > .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
height: auto;
}
```

Updated CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: absolute;
top: 36px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 1000;

width: 550px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
overflow:hidden;
background-color: #ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
color: #222;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
-ms-transition: all .3s ease;
-o-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;
height: 0;
}
.open  > .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
height:145px;
}
```

Comment: How can you set `height`? It can't be specific, that's the problem.